# Is it possible to make conference call between SIP and IAX2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asterisk, sip, voip

I have both SIP and IAX accounts in my app. From that app I did these:

Sip_1-------------------Call------------------Sip_2 [All ok, RTP/Audio Fine]

IAX_1------------------Call----------------IAX_2 [All ok, RTP/Audio Fine]

I am getting both SIP and IAX call Audio in my iOS app. But..

Sip_1----------------------------------IAX_1 [NO Audio!]

is it possible? Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: It sounds as it was a networking issue. Note that IAX (by the way, IAX does not use RTP)  traverses in a natural way the NAT while SIP doesn't. Why, then, does it work SIP - SIP?. Well, consider that RTP traffic SIP - SIP does not need to reach the server as RTP in an IAX - SIP does. It you are making tests from the same LAN, RTP does not have to traverse any NAT

Answer (score -2):

Yes, both Conference and Meetme commands for asterisk not care about source channel type.

None of asterisk command care.

So you can connect any number of channels from any channel driver.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. Can u tell me how can I do that from my iOS app side?